# grails 2.5 gets wrong locale resource bundle

Tags: grails

in our grails-app/i18n we have :

```
messages.properties
messages_en_US.properties
```

we are all in UK.  The servers is In UK.  Our laptops and computers are as UK as you can get. Nothing US at all.

Let us say we have a gsp with a label, such as:

```
  ${message(code: 'wibble.label', default: 'Bal. Cash'")}
```

in our messages.properties, we have

```
wibble.label = Bal. Cash
```

in our messages_en_US.properties, we have:

```
wibble.label = Bal. After
```

When we deploy this to our server, and hit from our UK windows 8 laptops with chrome, or our UK macs with safari, we see "Bal. After" as the label. It is incorrectly looking up the US local for some very bazaar reason.

The documentation clearly states it looks first for a match of lang and local, then lang, then nothing.

So it should do this:

1. look for messages_en_GB.properties
2. look for messages_en.properties
3. look for messages.properties

It is doing none of this, it just goes for the US version.

This is also the case when running the server locally on our laptops.

If I put &lang=en_GB on the command line, we get the right one.

Any ideas?

I also tried creating a messages_en.properties, but still gets the wrong one.

We actually want our US customers to have different labels etc, but this means our UK customers have to have the same labels.

### UPDATE

Found this website: http://www.localeplanet.com/support/browser.html
which returns the local.

In Chrome, on a UK system, which the OS is set to UK, and the browser language is set to English (not English US), it returns:

```
navigator.browserLanguage: undefined
navigator.language: en-US
```

IE gets the following:

```
navigator.browserLanguage: en-US
navigator.language: en-GB
```

So IE works, but none uses it.

Safari gives the same as chrome.

If we use the developer tools, to see what chrome is sending, we see:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
```

There you go, Chrome is hard coded to use en-US.  Good grief!